# Sympy match() doesn't work with multiple integrals?

Tags: match, sympy, integral

I want to obtain parameters of multiple integral ():

```
'''
from sympy import *
z = symbols('z', real=True)
nu = Function('nu', real=True, positive=True)(z)
xx1 = nu.integrate((z,0,z))
xx2 = xx1.integrate((z,0,1))
xx1
xx2
xx1.cancel
xx2.cancel
'''
```

[Integral and its structure in jupyterlab shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AX50.png)

Then with "wild"-type variables "Wi" I try to obtain parameters of integrals

```
''''
mm1 = Integral(W1,(W2,W3,W4))
mm2 = Integral(W1,(W2,W3,W4),(W5,W6,W7))
mm1
mm2
rr1 = xx1.match(mm1)
rr2 = xx2.match(mm2)
rr1
rr2.type()
''''
```

[matching result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHtOQ.png)

**It works for single integral but doesmt for multiple. Why?**

**SECOND** question is: why integration variable "z" is not obtained to "W2"?
**THIRD** question: why variable "z" is changed to symbol "_0" in "W1:nu(z)? ***How to do it right?***

Recommended in comment '.list' doesn't work:
[gives error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx5dM.png)

Comment: Maybe `xx2.limits` gives what you want.

Comment: doesn't work - see above (added)

Answer (score 0):

Every expression has args -- all you are (apparently) try to do is capture the arguments in variables. Wild are not needed for this:

```
>>> W1,(W2,W3,W4),(W5,W6,W7) = xx2.args
>>> W1,(W2,W3,W4),(W5,W6,W7)
(nu(z), (z, 0, z), (z, 0, 1))
```

Comment: But how to mark that question is answered
I don't find "the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer" on my screen
Help please

Comment: Can't help you there! :-)